# Insert Same Items In Cart CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to add 2 or more of same items in my cart, the problem is the new one items will replace quantity of the old one. My recent cart gave me this result:

```
SuperBike 31
```

What i want is like this:

```
SuperBike 11
SuperBike 20
```

Here's the code below:

```
$cart_item = array(
      'id'           => $this->input->post('id'),
      'productid'    => $this->input->post('productid'),
      'name'         => $this->input->post('name'),
      'qty'          => $amountReq
);

$insert = $this->cart->insert($cart_item);

    if ($insert) {
      echo count($this->cart->contents());
    } else {
      echo json_encode(false);
    }
```

Any Answer? Thank you

Comment: Can you explain, how are you manipulating items to cart when selected.

Comment: Its working fine, if you adding same item in cart it will increase the product quantity. Like if you add superbike 2 time in cart, cart will show you one item in cart but quentity will be 2.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this. Open `cart.php` file in `system/libraries/Cart.php`

replace

```
unset($this->_cart_contents[$rowid]);
```

With

```
if(isset($this->_cart_contents[$rowid]))
{
$this->_cart_contents[$rowid]['qty']++;
return $rowid;
 }

unset($this->_cart_contents[$rowid]);
```